# Small question about limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions

if i have $\displaystyle \lim_{|u|\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t,u)-a|u|^{\tau-2}u}{u}=0$ how to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{|u|\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t,u)}{|u|^{\tau-2}u}=a$ such that $\tau\in (1,2)$

- I tried the decomposition but the prof told me that is fals .

Help me please

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{f(t,u)}{\lvert u\rvert^{\tau-2}u}-a=\frac{1}{\lvert u\rvert^{\tau-2}}\cdot\frac{f(t,u)-a\lvert u\rvert^{\tau-2}u}{u}$

Now let $\lvert u\rvert$ tend to $0$ and note that $\tau\in(1,2)$ so $\tau-2\in(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well your setting imply that $f(t,u)=a|u|^{\tau-2}u +o(u)$ so 
$f(t,u)=|u|^{\tau-2}u(a + o (|u|^{2-\tau})$. Therefore 
$
\frac{f(t,u}{u|u|^{τ−2}}=a+o(|u|^{2−τ})\to a, when  |u|\to 0
$